# Scrollbar for contentplaceholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make the scrollbar of the hole page affect only on ConentPlaceHolder , i use  `style=" overflow:scroll; height: 500px;"` but it makes a special scrollbar for Conentplaceholder but i want the main scrollbar to do this effect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the best way to do it will be to use `position:fixed` on all your non-scrolling elements, and then just let the page flow normally.  This way, the main scrollbar will scroll the content while the rest of the page appears not to move, giving the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle of Dereleased's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/sQmhY/2/

Note that the padding of the #content div is the same as the heights of the #header and #footer divs.

Answer (score 0):

Demo
[scroll bar demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)
[Documentation](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller)